Optimizely 12 Upgrade - TinyMCE Plugin.js Error (EPiServer.CMS.TinyMce 4.8.1)
I'm upgrading from Optimizely 11 to 12 and encountering a "plugin.js" error for some TinyMCE plugins. I'm using the latest version (EPiServer.CMS.TinyMce 4.8.1).Here's my Serviceconfiguration class that has all episerver packages settings:
    
 public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddAlloy(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options => options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new SiteViewEngineLocationExpander()));
            services.Configure<TinyMceConfiguration>(config =>
            {
                config.Default()
               .AddEpiserverSupport()
              .Menubar("edit insert view format")
               .AddPlugin("epi-link").AddPlugin("epi-image-editor").AddPlugin("epi-dnd-processor")
               .AddPlugin("epi-personalized-content").AddPlugin("print").AddPlugin("preview").AddPlugin("searchreplace")
               .AddPlugin("autolink").AddPlugin("directionality").AddPlugin("visualblocks").AddPlugin("visualchars")
               .AddPlugin("fullscreen").AddPlugin("image").AddPlugin("link").AddPlugin("media").AddPlugin("table").AddPlugin("charmap")
               .AddPlugin("hr").AddPlugin("pagebreak").AddPlugin("nonbreaking").AddPlugin("anchor").AddPlugin("insertdatetime").AddPlugin("advlist").AddPlugin("lists")
               .AddPlugin("wordcount").AddPlugin("textpattern")
              .AddPlugin("code")
               .Toolbar("formatselect | numlist  bullist | outdent indent | alignleft aligncenter alignright  |  epi-personalized-content  | fullscreen | ", "bold italic underline superscript | forecolor backcolor | removeformat  | table | image  epi-image-editor | epi-link | code | ")
               .BlockFormats("Paragraph=p;Header 1=h1;Header 2=h2;Header 3=h3; Header 4=h4;Header 5=h5;Header 6=h6")
               .AddSetting("image_caption", true)
               .AddSetting("table_default_attributes", new { border = "0px" });
            });
            services.AddTinyMce().AddTinyMceSpellChecker();
            return services;
        }               
    }

Specific Issue:
I'm experiencing the "plugin.js" error, but none of the plugins mentioned in a relevant forum post (https://world.optimizely.com/forum/developer-forum/cms-12/thread-container/2023/5/upgrade-to-12-19-and-tiny-4-2-gives-console-errors/) seem to be the issue.
I specifically need the the above configured plugins & the following add ons but adding text color increases the count of plugin.js issue:
Table
Color Picker
Text Color
Code
So the question i have is how do I configure TinyMCE plugins in Optimizely 12 to ensure these plugins are available along with the others?
Is there something missing in my current configuration?
Are there specific steps I need to take to enable these plugins in EPiServer.CMS.TinyMce 4.8.1?
Lastly, are the specific plugins only available for paid version?
Any input is appreciated.
Regards.

Any failed network requests for plugin.js when the editor loads? Otherwise I'd remove all plugins and add them one by one until you run into the problem - it's possible one or more plugin names have changed between versions.

To address the name changes, here is the link on what all have changed
plugins renamed
Some are applicable for version 4 as well hence posting the link incase someone comes across the same issue
